# Traversing html table with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have an HTML table of indeterminate rows but a know number of columns. For each row, I need to locate each td having a class of "free". I then need to check the 3rd td following that, and if it also has a class of "free", I need to add a class of "start" to the original td. As an example a tr with 6 tds looking like this;

```
    <tr>
    <td class="free"></td> 
    <td class="free"></td>
    <td class="free"></td>
    <td class="free"></td>
    <td class="free"></td>
    <td class="not-free"></td>
    <td class="not-free"></td>
    </tr>
```

would then look like this:

```
    <tr>
    <td class="free start"></td> 
    <td class="free start"></td>
    <td class="free"></td>
    <td class="free"></td>
    <td class="free"></td>
    <td class="not-free"></td>
    <td class="not-free"></td>
    </tr>
```

I can find the index of each td but am not sure how to then locate the third index following that

```
    $('td.free').each(function() {
        var this_unit = $(this).index() 
         ......
    })
```

Comment: Add the code where you find the index of each td.

Comment: If you read the question, I need to know the status of the third following in order to change the status of the current td

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do this to loop through the td elements with the `free` class

```
$('td.free').each(function(i, td) {

    var $otherTd = $(td).next().next().next();

    // could be more specific by using $td.next('td') instead of just .next()

    if ($otherTd.hasClass('free')) {
        $(td).addClass('start');
    }
});
```

https://codepen.io/martincarlin87/pen/Njvxva

Comment: Hmm. hadn't thought about chaining .next(). However, getting error $td.next() not a function

Comment: There is `)` missing at the end. Use  td instead of $td and use like this  `$(td).next().next().next()` and `$(td).addClass('start');`

Comment: ah, updated the answer, wrote it without testing, just trying it out in a fiddle just now

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can use two loops. One to iterate through the `tr`, and another to go through the `td.free` elements in that row. For each `.free` element you can check the folllowing third `td` by using `eq()` and adding to the index of the current element. Try this:

```js
$('table tr').each(function() {
  var $tr = $(this);
  var $td = $tr.find('td');

  $td.filter('.free').each(function(i) {
    $(this).toggleClass('start', $td.eq(i + 3).hasClass('free'));
  });
});
```

```css
td { 
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px; 
 }
.free { background-color: #CCC; }
.not-free { background-color: #333; }
.start { background-color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="free"></td>
    <td class="free"></td>
    <td class="free"></td>
    <td class="free"></td>
    <td class="free"></td>
    <td class="not-free"></td>
    <td class="not-free"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```